# How to capture events of logout confirmation "Yes" and "No"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am setting up events in my project and wanted help in capturing properties logout_confirmation 1) user click on ”Yes”  2) user click on “No”

```
const analytics = { track: (...args) => console.log('track: ', ...args) }


const logout = () => {
analytics.track('account_logged_out') // Can capture logout button event
Modal.confirm({
title: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',
icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
maskClosable: true,
cancelText: 'No',
cancelButtonProps: { size: 'large' },
okText: ' Yes ',
okButtonProps: { size: 'large' },
onOk() {
  localStorage.removeItem('auth')
  setUser(null)
  Router.push('/')
},
})
```

Comment: `onOk`.........

Comment: thanks, onOk() when user click on Yes.. how to capture when user click on No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `onOk()`, and `onClose()` or `onCancel()`

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
Modal.confirm({
title: 'Are you sure you want to logout?',
icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
maskClosable: true,
cancelText: 'No',
cancelButtonProps: { size: 'large' },
okText: ' Yes ',
okButtonProps: { size: 'large' },
onOk() {
  localStorage.removeItem('auth')
  setUser(null)
  Router.push('/')
},
}).then(function(){}).catch(function(){});
```

Comment: Could you explain how to capture when the user doesn't select the OK property ?